# DyanmoDB get function alexa skill scoping issue

Tags: node.js, scope, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am having a scoping issue with a DynamoDB function that I'm using in my Alexa code (I'm pretty new to NodeJS in general) 
The following code is my launch handler and I have a variable named x inside of my handler. I am trying to set x to data that I'm getting from dynamoDB and to use it outside of the get function so that Alexa can speak it (as you see in the return). The statement in my get function is not changing the value of x outside of the get function itself. In other words, the x outside of my get function seems separate from the x variable inside of the get. I know that the x inside of the get function is actually being changed because I am logging it to console. Alternatively, I tried putting the return statement inside the get function (in the else block), but that did not work

```
const LaunchHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === `LaunchRequest`;
   },
   handle(handlerInput) {

   let x = "";

 DBClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", 
        JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        x = data.Item.Answer; //this is functioning properly, I am getting the data I want from the database, it is a string
    } }); 

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(x)
        .withShouldEndSession(false)
        .getResponse();
    },
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's a scope issue. I think that since the DBClient.get() method is asynchronous, the return statement is executing before the callback inside the DBCLient.get() method is executing.

Comment: Oh Okay thank you. How would you solve this then though?